Epic on FHIR Sandbox Alternative for Testing Epic Embedded Launch Integration
I integrated my application (let’s call it Acme) with Epic embedded launch. It is meant for the “Clinicians or Backend Systems” consumer type, and uses SMART on FHIR for security.
When we register an app on the Epic on FHIR website, the website assigns it two client IDs, a production one and a non-production one. Acme can only support one client ID at a time for the SMART on FHIR workflow.
If we ever go live with some client, the client will obviously use the production client ID. However, the only apparent way for me to test the embedded launch is through the Epic on FHIR sandbox (discounting the Epic testing harness, which doesn’t create launch tokens). The sandbox generates a launch token which always contains the non-production client ID. So basically, at one time, either the client can use the Acme embedded launch in their production environment or I can use it in the sandbox one.
If there is ever some problem on production, can I generate the launch token to replicate it for the same registered app that the client is using, without depending on the Epic on FHIR sandbox? Could the paid Vendor Services account have an alternative that allows me to include the production client ID in the launch token?

Which client ID is included during the launch will depend on which environment the app is being launched from. If you have a production issue, you will want to work with the customer to get the details from the customer's production environment (and the transactions in this scenario will be tied to the production client ID). Any attempts to recreate the issue in the Epic sandbox or the customer's nonproduction environment would be tied to the nonproduction client ID. The route you take (Epic on FHIR vs Vendor Services) won't change anything about this.
